# Correct way to Add new domains for Lets Encrypt on Debian 9

Tags: ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I have a server on Linode with 1-click install (Debian 9) .

After that I install Lets Encrypt by following Certbot official procedures.

```
https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/debianstretch-apache
```

**Everything works ok without any error. However, when i add another domain to the same server, it get warning by saying this new site is "Not Secure"**

By checking the following files

```
/etc/letsencrypt/live
```

I only manage to see **my1stdomain.com** So i think this is the main reason for the **my2nddomain.com to receive a warning "Not Secure"**

I can't find the official docs for add new domains on **certbot.eff.org**

What i found the most likely to be the correct way to add new domains are this command line

```
sudo -H ./letsencrypt-auto certonly --standalone -d my2nddomain.com -d www.my2nddomain.com
```

However, i don't dare to test it yet because I am afraid it may get error and cause the whole server not working. By then, my 1stdomain will also be effected.

Anyone can advice ?